# mongodb reached disk full on EC2, what is the best practices?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

Mongodb run on EC2 micro instance reached disk full. What options do I have?

1. attach a new EBS?
2. create a new instance?
3. create sharding?

Comment: I'd start a bigger instance and moved data there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to attach a new ESB if the performance was not an issue before and stop mongo move the data on the new disk and restart mongo with the new --dbpath.

Of course if you want to improve the performance and add some complexity to your solution create a new shard, but than you need to double check if your code it's shard proof :) (example: [MapReduce and sharding environment](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-ShardedEnvironments))

Comment: If the Instance type is OK and there is no problem with CPU/RAM size, how about create few EBS drives and make RAID 0 or 10 to make the performance better? Here are some good tips and guides for Amazon EC2 +MongoDB: http://www.10gen.com/presentations/webinar/mongodb-and-amazon-web-services-emea and http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv-2011/experiences-deploying-mongodb-on-aws